# Creating hierarchy from object name

Tags: python, outliner

Hello dearest people of the internet,

As a complete beginner, I would like to use your smart brains.

I have a list of objects, named to their specifications of the mesh in it. e.g.
tabletop.200.100.4
In this case a tabletop, 200cm length, 100cm width, 4cm thick

I need to split this into a hierarchie of empty nodes

`ItemCategory
-TabletopOption
--LengthCategory
---200cmOption
----WidthCategory
-----100cmOption
------*Object Mesh in here*`

Is there a way to automate this? Maybe with Python?

Comment: Hierarchy of what? Layers? Collections? Child Parent relations? What are empty nodes?